# Protocol mismatch error when trying to get contentWindow from iframe (only in latest iOS)

Tags: cordova

We have an iOS app that we're building using Cordova and Sencha Touch, and we're having trouble get the iframes in our app fully functional.

In iOS 13 whenever we attempt to get an iframe's contentWindow we get the following error:

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "https://oursite.com". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Is there a configuration we must change to allow this to work?